# How to position image in a cell range using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to move an image within a certain cell range.

I download it and add it up to my specified Excel sheet.
The image looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DEN6.jpg

I would like to resize the image to fit within a range like:

```vb
Set r = ws.Range("C17:O34")
```

To look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYkkO.jpg

The image can be a resized manually if need, but I need it within that cell range.

To select the image I tried:

```vb
Sub selectImage12()
    Worksheets("T-tilbud").Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 12")).Select
End Sub
```

To move it to the specified cells, I tried:

```vb
Set r = ws.Range by following this example:

Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim imagePath As String
Dim img As Picture

Set ws = Worksheets("CheckListIndustrialisation")
Set r = ws.Range("A1:D4")
imagePath = "C:\myImage.jpg"
Set img = ws.Pictures.Insert(imagePath)

With img
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Top = r.Top
    .Left = r.Left
    .Width = r.Width
    .Height = r.Height
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply code that you've specified in example to selected "Picture 12" then you can use this new example:

```
Sub selectImage12()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim img As ShapeRange

    Set ws = Worksheets("T-tilbud")
    Set r = ws.Range("A1:D4")
    
    Set img = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 12"))

    With img
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Top = r.Top
        .Left = r.Left
        .Width = r.Width
        .Height = r.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vasily!
It helped a lot. Apparently what I was missing that it is a ShapeRange and not just a Shape as I was declaring it in my tryouts.

Best regards, 
Daniel